# How to store a <select> in a model property?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am new to ASP.NET Core and Razor pages. I am trying to create a select drop-down list and get its value for further processing. I have the following in the view / Razor page (the `.cshtml` file):

```
<div class="field">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.FavouriteColour, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label" })
    <div class="control">
        <div class="select">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.FavouriteColour, new SelectList(Model.FavouriteColoursList, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @id = "favouriteColour", @name = "favouriteColour" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FavouriteColour, "", new { @class = "has-text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And then I have the following in the `OnPost()` method of the view model (the `.cshtml.cs` file):

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "My favourite colour is...")]
public string FavouriteColour { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FavouriteColoursList = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "White",
        Text = "White"
    },
    (...)
}
```

The page is displayed correctly and all options are visible in the drop-down but the OnPost() method fails to retrieve the selected value. The following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Colour: " + FavouriteColour);
Console.WriteLine("Colour (FORM): " + Request.Form["favouriteColour"] + " " + Request.Form["favouriteColour"].GetType());
```

Has the following output:

```
Colour:
Colour (FORM): White Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues
```

When I also try to `.GetType()` of the model property, I get a System.NullReferenceException which, combined with the information above, shows that the data is transferred correctly but for some reason fails to be assigned to the model property.

What's the root cause and how to resolve it?

Comment: For some reason it looks like views don't work with view models so my workaround is to create a separate model and use it instead. Any explanations why that is are welcome as answers.